# How to search Windows 10 folders inside specific parent folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I'm looking for a way to search inside different folders that have identical subfolders. Say my structure is

```
geometry/
--tests/
--notes/
mechanics/
--tests/
notes/
```

I would like to do something like introducing `geometry/tests` into the search bar and get that specific folder, because if I have many folders called `tests` the results end up cluttering the search results and it's hard to find what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Windows allows you to use the `path` search filter to narrow down the search.

Syntax is < **search word** > < space > < **path**: `your folder path` >

For example:
If i want to search for "win" within a folder called "Shortcuts",
my search term would be **`win path: y:\shortcuts`**

[image: search example]

**Advanced Query Syntax** for Windows Search can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/desktop/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference).
Although this is applicable to Windows Desktop Search 2.x, i have found that most of the search filters work in File Explorer search.